# No data to display in highcharts showing up with the data in Bubble Chart

Tags: charts, highcharts

I have a bubble chart in which on zoom a 'no data to display' message shows up. The no data to display module works fine on all other charts and even in bubble chart. Only this particular instance it shows up the message. And also the x-axis gridline is showing up outside the x-axis and y-axis content.Any ideas on how to avoid this?

Here is my code:

```
$(function () {


var chartObj =  {
        chart: {
            type: 'bubble',
            zoomType: 'xy',
            panning: true,
            panKey: 'shift',
            renderTo:'container'

        },

        legend: {
            margin: 0
        },

        xAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            tickInterval: 50,
            /*tickPosition: 'inside',*/
            tickLength: 0,
            title : {
                text : '<b>LOSS</b>' 
            },
        gridLineWidth: 1
        },

        yAxis: [{
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            tickInterval: 50,
            title : {
                text : '<b>PROFIT</b>',
                align:'middle',
                margin: 25,
            },
            gridLineWidth: 1
        },
        {
            min: 0,
            max: 0,

            title : {
                text : '<b>HIGH</b>',
                margin: -35,
                align:'low',
                y:-45
            },
            gridLineWidth:0,
            labels:{
                enabled:false
            },
            y:10
        },          
        {
            min: 0,
            max: 0,

            title : {
                text : '<b>LOW</b>',
                align:'high',
                margin:-35,
                y:55
            },
            gridLineWidth:0,
            labels:{
                enabled:false
            }
        }           
        ],
        title: {
            text: null
        },
          plotOptions: {
              bubble:{
                   minSize:10,
                   maxSize:100
                },
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
                x:0,
                formatter:function() {
                    return this.point.name;
                },
                style:{
                    "textShadow": "none !important",
                    "color":"black"

                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [
  {
    "name": "Two",
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Test100chara  Test100Chara  Test100char   Test100characters   Test100characters   Test100characterss",
        "x": 18,
        "y": 25,
        "z": 110000000
      },
      {
        "name": "Val1",
        "x": 4,
        "y": 0,
        "z": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "One",
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "2015_Initiative_1",
        "x": 65,
        "y": 59,
        "z": 106000000
      },
      {
        "name": "test",
        "x": 4,
        "y": 15,
        "z": 134200
      }
    ]
  }
]
};
new Highcharts.Chart(chartObj);
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/SoumitraM/j84Lfpn7/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like possibly bug, reported to our developers [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3378)